# orchard cms send email from custom form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am using Orchard 1.7.2. And I need to send all my custom forms (as contact-us) to one/two/three email which I can add on custom form edit page. I know that I can make it by using workflows/rules but I need to manage it on custom form page.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you write your own form, controller, etc. Much easier to just use workflows.

Comment: Yeah as Bertrand said, you would basically have to write your own Module. Why not try and use the tools already available within Orchard?